# Use of unassigned local variable, but variable is in fact initialized

Tags: c#, .net, variables, lambda, compiler-errors

I have the following little method:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object[], object>> _references = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object[], object>>();

public virtual void RegisterReference<R>(IEntityManager<R> referenceManager) where R : IPersistableEntity
{
    Type referenceType = typeof(R);
    Func<object[], object> operation = (args) => referenceManager.UseRepository<R>(repo => repo.BrowseAll(CreateReferenceExpression<R>(args)));

    if(!_references.ContainsKey(referenceType))
          _references.Add(referenceType, operation);
    else
          _references[referenceType] = operation;
}
```

I am getting a compilation error stating:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'operation'

[image: CompilationErrorImage]

Why is this being thrown? Clearly I am initializing my `operation` variable.

What's more strange though, is that if I initialize the variable to `null`, ***and then set it*** to my wanted value, the error is gone:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<object[], object>> _references = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object[], object>>();

public virtual void RegisterReference<R>(IEntityManager<R> referenceManager) where R : IPersistableEntity
{
    Type referenceType = typeof(R);
    Func<object[], object> operation = null;
    operation = (args) => referenceManager.UseRepository<R>(repo => repo.BrowseAll(CreateReferenceExpression<R>(args)));

    if(!_references.ContainsKey(referenceType))
          _references.Add(referenceType, operation);
    else
          _references[referenceType] = operation;
}
```

[image: ErrorFixedImage]

**NOTE**: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4, and targeting .NET 4.5

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with code that appears similar to yours. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. I have seen errors such as you describe when the variable is used in the anonymous method itself, but not when the variable is simply used in the same scope as where it's declared. Also, please state specifically what version tools you are using (VS, compiler, target framework, etc.)